# Encountered error while using read.csv in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file which has around 100 obj's in it. I tried to load the CSV file into R using the following command

```
x <- read.csv(file.choose(), header="TRUE", sep=',')
```

After selecting the file, I got an error message saying

> Error in !header : invalid argument type

Please let me know what's the error with this code snippet.

Comment: Provide some data in your file.

Comment: `header="TRUE"` should be `header=TRUE`.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BsfKB7S2ohsN4v_htUWZ3m4oBynKDoqLLcKjPohtZkU/edit#gid=0

Using this link i downloaded the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=',')
```